# Code won't create correct HMAC-SHA256 signature

Tags: php, signature, sha256, hmac

I am trying to creating a hash-based message authentication code (HMAC) using the HMAC-SHA256 protocol.

I have the Secret Key and String and also I know what should be the output.

The Output should be: i91nKc4PWAt0JJIdXwz9HxZCJDdiy6cf%2FMj6vPxyYIs

But I am getting 0ahkosb8sCjCJoKzOwtmrdIKQoJVZnjRqZCxcdgtMA8=

Here is my code

```
$canonicalStringGet = "GET\n/v2/tenants/12111048-53df-43b2-b67c-6543352be8d9\nAuroraKey=AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE\nTimestamp=2016-02-20%2001:51:09%20UTC\nfirst_name=John&last_name=Doe&middle_name=Billy%20Joe\n"; 
        
$sig = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $canonicalStringGet, "bPxRfiCbPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEYYEXAMPLEKEY", true));

echo $sig;
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: You are base64 encoding your result. Your "the output should be" string has a `%` character in it. The percent sign is not a [valid base64 character](https://base64.guru/learn/base64-characters). So you're never going to get the string you're expecting. Why do you think that is the output you should expect to see?

Comment: Base64 encode is wrong. You need to Base64UrlEncode. See my [gist](https://gist.github.com/markuszeller/50693e568213cbb5ac2a3a67f03317c7).